# Make REST API with GenServer key-value pairs

Tags: elixir

Hi I'm unsure as to how to pass in my genserver functions into Plug.Router

The query string I want to build is:

```
http://localhost:8000/search/?id=42&value="arabica"
```

I've been told to use:

```
conn = fetch_query_params(conn)
```

But don't know how to call my genserver function to fit into this

My get macro looks like this:

```
get "/search/id="{id}<>"&value="{value} do
    send_resp(Server.Database.search(id, value))
end
```

GenServer search function:

```
 def search(bucket, search_list) when is_list(search_list) do
    GenServer.call(bucket, {:search, search_list})
end
```

How can I insert the query parameters inside the get macro and call my genserver functions?

Many thanks.

Comment: any particular reason you are saving the state inside of a genserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router macros just provide a path for the request to match. They don't do the extraction of params (though you can use the `/users/:id` form if you have path params).

Then `Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params/2` doesn't get the params out of the conn, it parses them and puts them in `conn.query_params` and `conn.params`.

So you're probably looking to do something more like this:

```rb
get "/search" do
  # make params available on conn
  conn = fetch_query_params(conn)

  # do search on your GenServer
  case Server.Database.search(conn.params["id"], conn.params["value"]) do
    # assuming your GenServer returns this
    {:ok, results} ->
      # JSON encode or whatever you want to do
      send_resp(conn, 200, encode(results))

    # you could handle a wider variety of errors; this is just an example
    {:error, error} ->
      send_resp(conn, 500, encode(error))
  end
end
```

Since `fetch_query_params/2` meets the requirements to be a plug itself, you could even plug it into your pipeline:

```rb
plug :fetch_query_params

...

get "/search" do
  # conn already has query params
  case ... do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: the way you showed it, you can just do this inside of your controller if you pipe it through api pipeline.

Comment: Are you saying just plug `Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params/2`? That makes sense, I'll add it